# Internal e-mails

Tags: centos, email, sendmail, troubleshooting, configuration

We need to send mails from our domain (assume this is `example.com`) to our self. Now, the 'incoming' mails are handled by another server (from Google). We can send mails through `sendmail` to external e-mail addresses, but when we tried to send to ourselves, nothing happens! What can we do to enable this feature?

We are running CentOS with Sendmail/Apache2/PHP, mails are sent by PHP.

Comment: Can you post relevant sendmail logs?

Comment: Where are they located?

Comment: do *grep mail /etc/syslog.conf*, you will see a filename on RHS. Then send a test mail and look for relevant logs in the file. Paste them, then we will come to know what is the exact problem.

Comment: Also if you are getting bounce back message, that will be most helpful.

Comment: Remove your own domain on emitter from w class (/etc/mail/local-host-names and /etc/hosts maybe), check DOMAIN() dnl in sendmail config (sendmail.mc of grep sendmail.cf)

Comment: @Warren, He's asked 5 nearly incoherent questions, with basically no follow up, at least one of which I answered and never heard back from him. If he's even reading our answers, he's not responding. I'm certainly not putting any more effort into trying to help someone that that can't seem to follow basic norms. Bart also mentioned the same thing, though in a much nicer way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [mail hosted at Google, web server elsewhere](http://blog.postmaster.gr/2011/03/14/mail-hosted-at-google-web-server-elsewhere/)